# Really slow Ubuntu in dual boot, possibly driver issue?

Tags: dual-boot

So I'm running a new desktop and dual booting it with windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My PC has an i5 8600k.

Windows runs perfectly but Ubuntu is extraordinarily slow to the point where it's almost unusable. I think it may be because I don't have the correct drivers installed but I'm not sure of that's the issue or not.

I'm assuming I haven't provided all the nessiscary information so please ask for more if it's needed.

Essentially I want to know if anyone has had an issue running with the 8600k processor or a really slow Ubuntu. I'm very new to Linux and this forum.

Edit: 16 gig of ram and integrated graphics. With Ubuntu and windows installed onto partitions on a 128gig m.2 Intel hard drive.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling it? Do you have enough RAM? Try to install an other distro if nothing helps.

Comment: Consider [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/990366/edit) in the output of `top -b -n 1 > top.txt` and `dmesg > dmesg.txt`.

Comment: Could be a problem of missing graphics card drivers, especially if it's a very new (gaming) graphics card - you may need to install the proprietary drivers for it.

Comment: So I've updated info on my ram and graphics.  Sorry @J.Starnes what does     top -b -n 1 > top.txt  and      dmesg > dmesg.txt  do?

Comment: `top` is a command that outputs details about running processes. The output of `top` may provide insight into processes that are consuming abnormal amount of resources. The `b` flag runs it in batch mode, the `n 1` flag tells `top` how many times to run in batch mode. `>` is an output redirection, in this case it sends the output of the `top` command to the file `top.txt` in the terminals current directory.

Comment: `dmesg` will print the kernel ring buffer to the file `dmesg.txt` in the terminals current directory. It may provide a clue about hardware errors or miss configurations. When someone asks you to run a command you are unfamiliar with you can check its man page. See [man top](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) and [man dmesg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html)

Comment: I have this exact same problem too. Did you manage to fix it?